# is it possible to use a hardcoded list of values instead of a range in range-formulas?

Tags: excel, list, static, formula, hardcoded

I was wondering if I could hardcode an array or "range" into a formula.  So, for example, if I wanted to see if a month in B2 is March, April, June or July,  I would like to compress this this:

```
=COUNTIF(a1:a4,MONTH(B2))>0
```

where A1:a4 = 3,4,6,7

to simply:

```
=COUNTIF((3,4,6,7),MONTH(B2))>0
```

so that I do not need extraneous lists in other cells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, just use "{ }" rather than "( )" to surround your list of values.

```
=COUNTIF({3,4,6,7},MONTH(B2))>0
```

I didn't test if your logic worked but showed where to put the braces.

Comment: This seems to work for hardcoded numbers, which technically answers the question correctly, but not for hybrid constants/cell references... e.g.`=XIRR({-100,105},{42799,43164})` works but `=XIRR({-B6,105},{42799,43164})` doesn't

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work on a European system where the separator is a semicolon.
I tried it with semicolons inside the brackets, and all kind of brackets and parentheses, but couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0):

Use the SUMPRODUCT() formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({3,4,6,7}=MONTH(B2))*1)
```

This will not work as a conditional formatting formula, only as a worksheet formula.